# Would fewer Jedi be more powerful?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-force, sith

One of the drivers behind the 'Rule of Two' is that with fewer Sith, the dark side will become more concentrated in those users and they will be more powerful as a result. Is there any indication that the same is true for Jedi?

Comment: Power is not what Jedi are aiming for.

Comment: "One of the drivers behind the 'Rule of Two' is that with fewer Sith, the dark side will become more concentrated in those users" I've never heard this before.

Comment: I don;t think that's how the Force works.

Comment: @phantom42 - It's an idea I've seen before but I'm not sure of where people typically get it from; see [this answer of mine](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121689/22250) where I responded to someone who I think was misinterpreting some lines from the novel *Darth Plagueis* in a "power becomes more concentrated the less Sith there are" sort of way.

Comment: From https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127859/did-darth-bane-have-a-plan-for-after-the-republic-was-destroyed "The power of the dark side cannot be dispersed among the masses. It must be concentrated in the few who are worthy of the honor." From @Null's answer, referencing Bane's thoughts. It's something that quite often comes up in answers here

Comment: I don't think that means the power is literally concentrated, I think it just means the Sith are a bunch of elitists who don't want to share their power.

Comment: Probably. But only because of the [inverse ninja theory](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConservationOfNinjutsu), not becuase of any in-universe mechanic.

Comment: @Valorum - I believe your comment should have been: "That's not how the Force works" - Han Solo.

Comment: @Ghotir - *"Mrooowoowoowoowoowoow"* - Chewbacca

Comment: The evidence does seem to support this theory.  Rey, for example, was apparently able to successfully perform a Jedi mind trick with absolutely no training.  (We'll have to wait and see whether some other explanation for that is eventually provided.)

Comment: [Inverse ninja rule](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ConservationOfNinjutsu).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's not how <strike>the force works!</strike> or why the [Rule of Two](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_of_Two) works. The Rule of two was created by Darth Bane to allow the Sith Order to operate in secret, because greed and fighting amongst many Sith Lords is what caused their downfall in the first place.

The Rule of Two isn't also about concentrating power. It is a cycle whereby the Master embodies power, and the Apprentice craves it.

So, since it isn't even true for Sith, it certainly isn't true for Jedi.

Comment: I guess if your "brand" is backstabbing evil-doers, more would just create bedlam.  I had friends who always chose evil characters in D&D, and, needless to say, they were usually re-starting with characters every week.

Comment: Exactly, it's not like the force itself is more powerful cause it's concentrated or whatever. It's to keep weaker groups from killing stronger individuals. If followed correctly then each successive leader of the Sith will be more powerful than the last.

Answer (score 8):

To the best of my knowledge, the idea that the Rule of Two "concentrates" the dark side into fewer Sith and makes them even more powerful is only mentioned in the [Bane trilogy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Bane_trilogy), which is Legends. Thus **there is no evidence in canon that either the light or the dark side can be made more powerful if "concentrated" into fewer Jedi or Sith, respectively.**

The Bane trilogy does explicitly mention Bane's belief that the Rule of Two served a secondary purpose of concentrating the dark side into fewer users and thus making it more powerful:

> “The power of the dark side is strongest if it is concentrated in one vessel,” Bane replied. “Not spread out among many. I did it for the sake of the dark side.
>
> <sub>***Star Wars: Path of Destruction*, p. 285**</sub>

The main purpose of the Rule of Two was to stop the infighting among the Sith, though (emphasis added):

> *By its very nature, the dark side invites rivalry and strife. This is the greatest strength of the Sith: it culls the weak from our order.*
>
> **The constant battling of the Sith since the beginning of recorded history served a necessary purpose: it kept the power of the dark side concentrated in a few powerful individuals.** The Brotherhood had changed all that. There were now a hundred or more Dark Lords following Kaan, but most were weak and inferior. The Sith numbers were greater than they had ever been, yet they were still losing the war against the Jedi.
>
> ***The power of the dark side cannot be dispersed among the masses. It must be concentrated in the few who are worthy of the honor.***
>
> ...
>
> The Jedi would always remain united in their cause. The Sith would always be brought low by infighting and betrayals.
>
> <sub>***Star Wars: Path of Destruction*, p. 237**</sub>

Note that all of these quotes indicate that it is in the nature of the dark side *only* to benefit from concentration in fewer individuals. Bane believed that the Sith infighting served to cull the weak and concentrate the power of the dark side in a few individuals. The Rule of Two was designed to stop the infighting (which would weaken the Sith as a whole against the Jedi), and the concentration of the dark side into two individuals was a beneficial side effect. The Jedi are "always united", though, so there is no concentration of the light side into a few individuals. Thus, **in Legends, only the dark side seems to benefit from being concentrated into fewer individuals. I suppose it is *possible* that the light side benefits as well (in the rare event that the Jedi are mostly exterminated, for example) but we can't be sure because only Bane talks about the Force being concentrated and he was not familiar with the light side.**

Comment: it could also be a matter of interpretation as to specifically what 'power' is being referenced in terms of concentration. Does it mean actual ability - like, with only two Sith they have more 'power' concentrated in them so they can move planets out of orbit as opposed to barely being able to lift an X-Wing - or is it talking about natural power for lack of a better word? Meaning - there are only two people to share the 'power' and spoils of leadership and control - which would be more of a consolidation type of concentration

Comment: @NKCampbell The "power" being referred to here is of the dark side itself, so I don't think it means power in the sense of leadership and control -- it sounds like power as in actual ability.

Answer (score 2):

Not canon (yet...) but I have a theory that the Force is like 1 reservoir, and the Force sensitive people are like conduits from it. If you shut off (or kill) a huge number of the conduits, the pressure behind the operational ones greatly increases. The thing that made me think this besides the rule of two with the Sith, is now we have Kylo Ren who can hold blaster shots in mid air, nobody has ever done that before. Why? I think with a galaxy full of force users the Force was merely a trickle and now when it has an outlet it's a roar.

Again, just a theory.

Comment: But Kylo Ren is (believed to be) post-Sith, and it remains to be seen if the First Order does or does not follow the Rule of 2. If it does not follow the Rule, then there could be MORE outlets for that dark side "pressure".

Answer (score 0):

So, it sounds like Bane is saying there is a finite about of dark force within a local area.  If 100 users were able to tap into that with 100% efficiency, they would each have 1/100th of the power, perhaps sufficient to hold their own against a jedi.  BUT if only 2 were there with 50% of the available power, they would be a 'force' (pun intended) to be reckoned with.  Not only would they be more powerful, but they would also instill more fear in their opponent, which they can use to even greater advantage.  Not to mention, it would be easier to be covert, less costly, able to fight on more fronts, and lower chance of intelligence loss.  Suffice it to say, their enemies, namely the jedi were more concerned about a couple powerful Sith than 1000 wannabes.